# Range Of Dates Over Conditional Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of startDates and EndDates where three YES/NO attributes exist:

[image: Table]

I need a range from the minimum startDate to the maximum endDate when any attribute (1,2, or 3) is equal to 'Y'. There also needs to be a range for the startDate to endDate when all attributes are equal to 'N'. So, the results would be something like the table below:
[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt36h.png)

I've tried a common table expression that failed miserably and something like the following:

```
select 

case
when ATTR1 = 'Y' or ATTR2 = 'Y' or ATTR3 = 'Y'<br>
then 'Y'<br>
ELSE 'WAIVE' END AS ATTR<br>
, min(startDate)    , max(endDate)<br>
from attribute_table_view<br>
group by ATTR, startDate
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can enumerate the groups by counting the number of N/N/N rows up to each row.  Then aggregate:

```
select min(startdate), max(enddatre)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when attr1 = 'N' and attr2 = 'N' and attr3 = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by startdate) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where  attr1 <> 'N' or attr2 <> 'N' or attr3 <> 'N'
group by grp
```